# message-filter onUnaccepted not breaking execution when used in "mule:choice" in custom policy mule 3

Tags: filter, mule

I am working on a custom policy in mule 3. When I am using message-filter inside mule:choice, on onUnaccpted, execution of next statement DOES NOT stop.

if I do not use mule:choice, execution of next statement stop on onUnaccepted in message-filter.

I need to use message-filter in mule:choice, can you please let me know how to stop next statement execution on message-filer onUnaccepted.

I have provided example below:

Case 1:

```
<before>
    <mule:logger level="INFO" message="Logger 0"/>
    <mule:message-filter onUnaccepted="policyViolation">
        <mule:expression-filter expression="true==false" />
    </mule:message-filter>
    <mule:logger level="INFO" message="Logger 1"/>
</before> 

<mule:processor-chain name="policyViolation">
    <mule:logger message="The custom policy filtered the message #[message.getId()] based on a MEL query" level="DEBUG" />
    <mule:set-property propertyName="http.status" value="403"/>
    <mule:set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
    <mule:set-payload value='{ "error" : "Custom Policy: {{ denied-message }}"}'/>
</mule:processor-chain>
```

Output: 403 - {"error": "Custom Policy: Access denied"}
and **DOES NOT** log message Logger 1.
execution breaks when onUnaccepted

Case 2:

```
   <before>
        <mule:logger level="INFO" message="Logger 0"/>
        <mule:choice>
            <mule:when expression="true==false" >
                <mule:logger level="INFO" message="Logger 1"/>
            </mule:when>
            <mule:otherwise>                           
                <mule:message-filter onUnaccepted="policyViolation">
                    <mule:expression-filter expression="true==false" />
                </mule:message-filter> 
            </mule:otherwise>
        </mule:choice>
        <mule:logger level="INFO" message="Logger 2"/>
    </before> 

    <mule:processor-chain name="policyViolation">
        <mule:logger message="The custom policy filtered the message #[message.getId()] based on a MEL query" level="DEBUG" />
        <mule:set-property propertyName="http.status" value="403"/>
        <mule:set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
        <mule:set-payload value='{ "error" : "Custom Policy: {{ denied-message }}"}'/>
    </mule:processor-chain>
```

Output: 403 - {"error": "Custom Policy: Access denied"}
and LOGS message Logger 2. after message filter onUnaccepted, execution does not break and continues

DO NOT want to print Logger 2.

Comment: Are these examples MUnit tests?

Comment: @aled this is in custom policy

Answer (score 0):

`onUnaccepted` doesn't seem to play well with MUnit. I have seen in the past that using filters with `onUnaccepted` produce unexpected results with MUnit. I recommend to avoid using it at all. I prefer to use [Validators](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/validations-module), which throw exceptions.

Comment: thanks for the response @aled. I am using this filer in mule:choice in custom policy

Comment: I'm not sure it will change anything. I don't think MUnit supports onUnaccepted.